# Simple regular expression for (x,y) number

Tags: regex

someone can help me how to implement the following pattern as a regular expression?

> apple(x,y);
>
> Where  `0 <= x,y <= 100`

So valid results would include the following:

```
apple(0,0);
apple(0,10);
apple(77,12);
apple(100,0);
apple(100,100);
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks so much

Comment: Did you mean the C sense of `0 <= x` _and_ `y <= 100` ? Its better written as `x >= 0, y <= 100`, or is it some other thing you had in mind?

Comment: 0 <= x <= 100 and  0 <= y <= 100

Comment: Well, just undeleted my post then. Be sure to use something that works. As of now, Kasramvd's answer is not quite right.

Comment: Yea, u say ture, His Expression accepted apple(832324324988,100);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a number range tool I get something like this

`apple\(0*(\d|[1-9]\d|100),0*(\d|[1-9]\d|100)\);`

```
 apple
 \(
 0*
 (               # (1 start)
      \d 
   |  [1-9] \d 
   |  100
 )               # (1 end)
 ,
 0*
 (               # (2 start)
      \d 
   |  [1-9] \d 
   |  100
 )               # (2 end)
 \);
```

Comment: Do you know, how to declarate a string with this filter? in Java

Comment: I found answer String filter = "apple\\(0*(\\d|[1-9]\\d|100),0*(\\d|[1-9]\\d|100)\\);";

Comment: @vihkat - In Java, escapes have to be escaped inside quotes. `String filter = "apple\\(0*(\\d|[1-9]\\d|100),0*(\\d|[1-9]\\d|100)\\); "`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a character class to specify the range of your number and the quantifier `{}` to limit the repetition :

```
apple\([0-9]+,(?:[0-9]{1,2}|100)\);
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/eG8kE6/2

Read more about regex http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Thats amazing, thank you! I cant learn expression writing because i need this for analyze a mini language code and make objects from code. Thanks so much!